# How to find occurrence of pattern with Open CV on IOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, image-processing, opencv

I have an image which contains some object (say, a hat). Also I have separate picture of exactly the same hat. My question is: being given the pattern, image and OpenCV library  how can I conclude whether the pattern is included in the image - or not? Description of algorithm or even some code would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a very complicated task. What do you need it for, and how important is performance?

Comment: well, I want to find predefined image inside the bigger one, or at least to know whether it appears there,that's all. Performance is important, say, I expect to obtain an answer in no more than 1 millisecond

Answer (score 1):

Try [TemplateMatching](http://www.aishack.in/2010/01/template-matching/) or SURF image match. Both are implemented in OpenCV. An [example](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/branches/2.3/opencv/samples/c/find_obj.cpp) code for SURF can be seen in OpenCV samples. Check out its [android implementation demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUyHHIs7ByI).You can try that.